# Jenkins marking builds as pass with failures

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to have a Jenkins job that fires off other jobs and fails if they fail.

I have the following Jenkinsfile

```
#!groovy
String hipChatRoom = "${HC_ROOM}" //'Ecom WSS'
def projectPath = "${projectPath}"
def numberOfNodes = "${numberOfNodes}".toInteger()
def parallelStageMap = [:]
def failure = false


def generateStage(int i) {
    return {
        node("Cypress") {
            try {
                build(job: 'Cypress-Kickoff', wait: true, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH_NAME', value: BRANCH_NAME], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'recordKey', value: recordKey], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'projectPath', value: projectPath], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CI_BUILD_ID', value: BUILD_ID], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ID', value: i.toString()]])
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println e
                failure = true
            }
        }
    }
}

stage("Cypress Run") {
    node("Cypress") {
        currentBuild.setDisplayName("${projectPath}")
        deleteDir()
        git url: 'http://github.com/REPO/repo.git', branch: BRANCH_NAME
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
            parallelStageMap["stage" + i] = generateStage(i)    
        }
        parallel(
            parallelStageMap
        )
    }
}

if (failure) { 
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
}
```

If I go in and terminate one of the Cypress The build still passes

```
[stage0] Starting building: Cypress-Kickoff #438
[stage2] Starting building: Cypress-Kickoff #439
[stage1] Starting building: Cypress-Kickoff #440
[stage3] Starting building: Cypress-Kickoff #441
[stage4] Starting building: Cypress-Kickoff #437
[Pipeline] [stage1] echo
[stage1] hudson.AbortException: Cypress-Kickoff #440 completed with status ABORTED (propagate: false to ignore)
[Pipeline] [stage1] }
[Pipeline] [stage1] // node
[Pipeline] [stage1] }
[Pipeline] [stage0] }
[Pipeline] [stage0] // node
[Pipeline] [stage0] }
[Pipeline] [stage4] }
[Pipeline] [stage4] // node
[Pipeline] [stage4] }
[Pipeline] [stage3] }
[Pipeline] [stage3] // node
[Pipeline] [stage3] }
[Pipeline] [stage2] }
[Pipeline] [stage2] // node
[Pipeline] [stage2] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It works if I use "catchError" however I cannot use that as I need to post a message to Hipchat of Slack on failues.

How do I get the job to fail if any of the parallel jobs fail?

Comment: Does you code go in `if(failure)` ? Add a trace to check that. If not, you have to throw exception instead of set failure=false and catch exception around stage("Cypress Run")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood well, but what about using `currentBuild.result` after catchError ? I often use **try / catch / finally** to manage this.

[Official Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result)

Also, you can force the job to fail with the line `currentBuild.result='FAILURE'`

```
node {
    catchError {
        // Do your job
    }
    if(currentBuild.result=='FAILURE')
        // Notify
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch the exception, but don't throw it again after you're done handling it. You can add `throw e` in the `catch` block and remove the `failure` variable.